# Make background see-through in WMS layer

Tags: qgis, raster, wms

I can't figure out how to make the background transparent. Its a WMS layer/raster in EPSG3006

http://geodpags.skogsstyrelsen.se/arcgis/services/Geodataportal/GeodataportalVisaNyckelbiotop/MapServer/WmsServer

Comment: Load it as `png`.

Comment: look at the capabilities file and see if it's marked as opaque if not set TRANSPARENT=true in the get map request

Comment: I changed it to png but the second part i dont know where to look

Comment: Do you have access to the WMS server? That is where the capabilities file is located. In other words is th4e WMS produced by you or by someone else? You could try out different blending modes in and color settings in Properties --> Symbology if you cant change the settings on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the GetCapabilities response for the service:

> http://geodpags.skogsstyrelsen.se/arcgis/services/Geodataportal/GeodataportalVisaNyckelbiotop/MapServer/WmsServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

You can see that the GetMap operation supports png, which is the format you need for transparency:

```
<GetMap>
    <Format>image/bmp</Format>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Format>image/tiff</Format>
    <Format>image/png</Format>
    <Format>image/png8</Format>
    <Format>image/png24</Format>
    <Format>image/png32</Format>
    <Format>image/gif</Format>
    <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
```

Look at the Layer information for the layer of interest, we have queryable="1" meaning you can do a GetFeatureInfo request but no opaque attribute is specified.

```
<Layer queryable="1">
    <Name>Nyckelbiotop_Skogsstyrelsen</Name>
```

For meaning of opaque see the following from the specification

> 7.2.4.7.4
> Opaque vs. transparent layers

> If the optional Boolean attribute opaque is absent or false, then maps made from that Layer will generally have significant no-data areas that a client may display as transparent. Vector features such as points and lines are
> considered not to be opaque in this context (even though at some scales and symbol sizes a collection of features might fill the map area). A true value for opaque indicates that the Layer represents an area-filling coverage. For
> example, a map that represents topography and bathymetry as regions of differing colours will have no transparent areas. The opaque declaration should be taken as a hint to the client to place such a Layer at the
> bottom of a stack of maps.

> This attribute describes only the Layer’s data content, not the picture format of the map response. Whether or not a Layer is listed as opaque, a server shall still comply with 7.3.3.9 regarding the GetMap TRANSPARENT
> parameter: that is, the server shall send an image with a transparent background if and only if the client requests TRANSPARENT=TRUE and a picture FORMAT that supports transparency.

So there should be no issue with you retrieving a transparent image in QGIS

In the case of this service one thing to note is that the layer is scale layered:

```
<MaxScaleDenominator>1889880.952381</MaxScaleDenominator>
```

so when you are zoomed out too far and have a non transparent image format like JPEG or TIFF you just get a white image (there is no styling showing), and similarly if you have a transparent image format like PNG you get a transparent image, that shows absolutely nothing.

I would say that the extent of the map seems to be set too big for the intended projection of EPSG:3006

```
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
    <westBoundLongitude>-30.000000</westBoundLongitude>
    <eastBoundLongitude>60.000000</eastBoundLongitude>
    <southBoundLatitude>-90.000000</southBoundLatitude>
    <northBoundLatitude>90.000000</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
```

is way out of bounds.

But if you are zoomed in to the right part of Sweden, then yes it works.

[image: Transparent layer in EPSG:3006 with png]

As opposed to JPEG

[image: Opaque layer in EPSG:3006 with JPEG]

Comment: thanks  i am beginning to understand, but I have yet to learn about the GetMap request, i cant understand where I change Transparent=True but with still more googling i will probably solve it

Comment: note it's `TRUE` not `true` that is the value is case sensitive according to the specification (as are all parameter values).    If you are using a client like QGIS though (as you have tagged) you just need to point the client to the service and it will work out the parameters that need to be sent

Comment: Where do you change? I have been looking to youtube but no video shows how to change Transparent=TRUE only adding WMS, (feel so stupid)

Comment: Just select png as the image type, Qgis will make the request with the correct parameter